# Show that tetrahedral has a segment perpendicular to a plane

Tags: geometry

[image]
In this tetrahedral, I have that

$$DC = DA, AB = BC$$

and also, I have that angle $DBA$ is $90^\circ$.

I need to show that at least one segment is perpendicular to a plane in this tetrahedral.

What I tried:

We're using the theorem that says that if a segment is perpendicular to 2 segments, then it's perpendicular to the plane defined by these two segments. Therefore, since I think that $DB$ is perpendicular to the plane $ABC$, I just need to show that $DB$ is perpendicular to $BC$, then we have the $2$ lines necessary to prove. I think I can use some property of similarity, since we have that triangle $DCA$ and $ABC$ are similar (LLL). Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instead showing that $\triangle DBA$ and $\triangle DBC$ are congruent.